# Software to model human body falling

Tags: simulation, modeling

I need to identify software in which I can model the trajectory of a human being falling within a complex structure - e.g. as if someone is falling from a tree and hits a series of branches on the way down. Active participation by the human would be irrelevant. Is there such software?

Comment: What level of detail do you want in the motion of body parts (or can that just be a point mass)? What price? What OS?

Comment: Do you want to visualize it realistically? Then a gaming engine would be feasible. For doing predictions ("these data from our motion capture sensors could reflect a human body falling through trees"): you could do this for instance in Matlab. By the way I wonder where you might get training datasets from ;-)

Comment: I think that there would have to be a reasonable amount of detail - a spherical object, for instance, would interact with the structure in a way that a limbed object would not.

Price would be irrelevant as would the OS.

I think visualisation would be useful to convince a (non-mathematically inclined) customer ;-)

Comment: I seen some [interesting video](https://youtu.be/nj_Dtj7c0Lc) on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwF6yYbIFJmB5ynAkzq9Psg) for an incoming software [cascadeur](https://cascadeur.com) but is still closed beta (you can try to apply)